# Android sqlite delete from listview

Tags: android, sqlite

Im having problems with deleting items from listview(and database). So far i have followed this example:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html but i dont like the delete there (button that always delets first one).

Here is my activity class:

```
public class FirstActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    final ShoppingSQL shoppingSQL = new ShoppingSQL(this);
    List<ShoppingData> list = shoppingSQL.getAll();

    ArrayAdapter<ShoppingData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ShoppingData>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
       this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.w("DELETED", " DELETED");
                shoppingSQL.delete((int)id);
                return true;
            }
        });     

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.w("CLICKED", "CLICKED");
}
```

}

As you can see i have the listner for long clicks set up and also the delete method that requires an ID. The probelm is with the ID, the one im giving it at the moment seems to be just the order number (0, 1, 2, 3) - not the actual id in db. So, my question is how do i get the real id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can get your Id of Shoping data by

```
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.w("DELETED", " DELETED");

                //here You can get your id by 

                list.get(position).getID();

                //getID id the getter method of shoppingdata ,here you can declare your method for ID as whatever you have in shopping data
                shoppingSQL.delete((int)list.get(position).getID());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

For delete items

adapetr.remove(list.get(i));
then call notifydatasetchanged on listview

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I got two more little questions if you have the time.
1) Why does eclipse say that list has to be final? I dont think list can be final cos it has to be able to change?
2) How can i "refresh" the list after deleting? I tried "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" but that didnt seem to work - maybe because it also wanted me to put adapter as final and it wont change it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the item that is selected from the ListView and then check its ID from the List as follows,

```
    String selectedItem =(String) (MyListView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    int ItemID = list.indexOf(selectedItem);
    shoppingSQL.delete(ItemID);
```