# I can't delete a row from my Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

This question was probably asked before but other questions did not have similar code to mine.  My SQLite table is pretty simple: all I have are my ID and TO_DO_NAME columns and I want to remove a row when a ListItem is calling onLongClick().  I already have implemented the long click functionality but when I restart the app, the same item is there.  This is my DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String TO_DO = "todo";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_TO_DO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TO_DO
                + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TO_DO_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String todo) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TO_DO, todo);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this is my **updated** method that takes care of the single row delete:

```
public int itemDeleteFromDatabase(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int deleteFromDatabase = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID +  "=" + id, null);
    listItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    return deleteFromDatabase;
}
```

I'm calling the method from my List item long click:

```
listItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int position, long id) {
                toDoItems.remove(position);
                itemDeleteFromDatabase(position);
                MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Like I said, it's still there.

**UPDATE**

This is where I'm adding data from:

```
public void addItem(View v){
        EditText newItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemInputEditText);
        String item = newItem.getText().toString();
        databaseHelper.insertData(item);
        adapter.add(item);
        newItem.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: from where are you adding data to your sqlite?

Comment: Dynamically from my textview.

Comment: post that code please

Comment: check edit.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433142/android-sqlite-delete-from-listview

Comment: @ZohraKhan You're just posting another question.  Which line of code in that question helps me?  Did you read through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code  `itemDeleteFromDatabase(position);` position is not your `ID` which is in your database. If you want to delete on basis of `ID` then you have to get `ID` from array which you bind in `RecyclerView`.

and if you bind RecyclerView from directly using Curosr from Database then you have to pass `long id`in your `itemDeleteFromDatabase` function. because it returns a auto index id of your database.

Comment: I'm not using a RecyclerView and how am I suppose to get the ID from the database and delete the row accordingly?

Comment: if you bind list based on Cursor then use `long id` as a parameter of your delete function. it will delete item from database based on that `id`. this `id` is nothing but its a auto raw_id of your database.

Comment: have you got what exactly i am trying to saying to you?

Comment: Yes but now the problem is that I can delete only 1 item from the database and that is it.  Not more.  Once I restart the app, only that particular item is missing.

Comment: after delete item, you have to again `setAdapter` because the item is not refreshing after you delete from the database. if you are a directly bound list from cursor then you have to do like `adapter.swapCursor(cursor_update);
`

Comment: I did that (check my updated delete method above).  It works great the first time.  When I close my app and open it again, none of the items in the list are deleted.